# How to get a mortgage soon when self-employed in 1-person LLC that is <6 months old

Tags: united-states, mortgage, self-employment, mortgage-qualification

In Jan 2022, I got hired to work (remotely, living in USA) as a senior software engineer for a non-US company that was unable to hire me as a W2 full-time employee; they required me to create an LLC (in mid Jan 2022).

We signed a contract where they pay me a fixed amount monthly. The contract is "at will" (either side could terminate for any reason), but the spirit of it is that we both want the arrangement to continue indefinitely. They wrote the contract as a 12-month agreement that automatically annually renews. Additionally, there is a financial "retention" incentive where I get a large bonus after the first year and then monthly bonuses for the following three years (for continuing to work for them).

My partner and I want to buy a house quickly. Yesterday, we found one that is a great fit at a great price. I wanted to put in an offer, but 3+ lenders I've spoken with have said that my employment situation is too unusual, even though I'm a senior software engineer making plenty of money.

They say that their "guidelines are black and white" and that I need to show tax returns and profit/loss statements for 1-2 years for my LLC.

My partner and I can't wait until March 2023 (or whenever it is that our financial statements will all be available to enable us to file taxes).

How can I find a lender who specializes in this kind of atypical case?

(Rocket Mortgage and Better.com do not.)

Comment: product recommendations are [off topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but there do appear to be some lenders that don't require tax returns, and can work with bank statements and your written contract instead. Best of luck on oyur mortgage hunt.

Comment: What kind of lenders are you approaching? I would try small local companies rather than large "nationally advertised" lenders if you haven't already.

Comment: Your situation requires the lenders to literally take your word for a tons of money. Foreign employer, SMLLC, no W2, all these are not just unusual - they present a significant risk to the bank. If you lose your job you won't even be eligible for unemployment benefits, as minuscule as they are in the US.

Comment: @GOATNine Thanks. If you can share any names that you've heard of, I'd appreciate it, as I've been struggling to find ones who operate that way.

Comment: @chepner Rocket Mortgage and Better.com and Orchard are probably all "large nationally advertised lenders", but then I've also heard from a few smaller ones whose names I hadn't heard before (including the lender that our realtor recommended locally). Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @littleadv Well, it's frustrating that an entire industry exists with "credit bureaus" who invasively track an incredible amount of data and provide scores like 812 Excellent, but then this reputation I thought I'd built of being a perfect borrower (always paying credit card statements in full, never being late on a payment, rent always paid on time, etc) seems to matter not at all.  Not to mention having a career that enables me to easily attract job offers with salaries that are high enough to pay the mortgage payments. I would have expected that compared to most people, I'm a safer bet.

Comment: @Ryan your problem is not with the credit reporting system or the credit scoring, these seem to be working just fine for you. Your problem is with the banks' underwriting guidelines. The credit history and score are just one input into the underwriting decision-making process, but not the only one. While you *think* that you're a safer bet, underwriters disagree. They have their own way of determining your risk, and your unique situation creates (at least an appearance of) much more risk.

Comment: Check with your realtor who may know a mortgage company/bank and/or a mortgage broker who is willing to work with unusual situations.

Comment: The reason I suggested a smaller company is that the large companies have a much larger pool of potential borrowers, so they can reject anyone that seems like a less than perfect risk. Smaller lenders, with a smaller pool of borrowers, may be more willing to look at specific circumstances rather than rejecting you out of hand.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I just heard that suggestion elsewhere too, so I'll poke around local credit unions etc.

Comment: I’ll second the idea that you need a small lender for a non conforming loan. The issue you’re bumping in to is the machine for conforming mortgage loans. The machine says employment criteria of X, because ultimately the organization underwriting your loan only cares to sell the loan, they will then bundle it up and sell it. You need a lender that underwrites you and keeps the debt.

Answer (score 1):

We applied to ~15 places, and only a local credit union was willing to work with us.

Then, before we even did the paperwork, my company luckily also was able to open a US entity and convert me to W-2.

So then most of the other lenders became interested in working with us too!

But we moved forward with the first company since we appreciated that they were reasonable even before the W-2 conversion.